# Get transaction id after contract function call

Tags: web3js, truffle, dapp-development

I'm using truffle.

How can I get transaction id before it is mined? For example:

```
contract.purchase(price).then(function(tx) {
    console.log("Success");

}).catch(function(e){
    console.log(e);
});
```

In that case I only get the tx after the transaction is mined. But I want to have the ability to print the transaction id as soon as it has been created.

I tried using callback function, like:

```
contract.purchase(price, function(error, tx) {
if(error != null)
    return;
console.log(tx);
})
```

but I get error "invalid address"

I have tried using `web3.eth.filter('pending')` and `web3.eth.filter('latest')` but I only get the id after it is mined. I'm testing it in TestRpc.

Comment: Try `contract.purchase.sendTransaction(price).then(function (tx) { console.log(tx); });`. It should not wait but return immediately.

Answer (score 10):

I've tried with a sample contract

```
const tx = await MyContract.MyMethod.sendTransaction(MyParams);
console.log(`Tx: ${tx}`);
```

It will return immediately without waiting for the transaction to be mined. The difference is the method was not called as `MyMethod(MyParams)` but `MyMethod.sendTransaction(MyParams)`.

Comment: That's good, but I'm looking for a way to keep waiting also for the receipt (after tx is mined). Is there any?

Comment: @tomericco Web3 v1.0 has [promiEvents](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#eth-sendtransaction-return) that support waiting for the transaction to be mined and trigger an event 'transactionHash' when the hash is available. For truffle and web3 v0.20 once you have the transaction hash you can set a timer to periodically check for the transaction to be mined (internally truffle does exactly that).